# Why is create-next-app command creating .tsx files instead of .js files?

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js

It seems to only be a problem when I add with-tailwindcss to the end of the command line? `npx create-next-app -e with-tailwindcss project_name`

Answer (score 1):

Proper way to install Next.js with Tailwind CSS would be:

```
npx create-next-app project_name
cd project_name
npm install -D tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer
npx tailwindcss init -p
```

More here: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/nextjs

Answer (score 0):

The `with-tailwindcss` template you are using is setup with typescript.

You can find the source [here on GitHub](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-tailwindcss),